# How to export data from published Power BI report?

Tags: report, powerbi, dashboard

I want to get the data from published Power BI report which is embedded in a web page as a dashboard. Is there any way to do this? What technology/tool can be used to read data of a dashboard embedded in a web page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't see the visual header (ellipsis) where you can click `Export data`, then no. This means that the owner of the report hide this on purpose or [the admin disabled it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-portal#export-data). Also exporting data requires Pro or Premium and edit permissions on the dataset and report, which you may not have.

If you see the visual header, then you can, but keep in mind that there are [some limitations](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Export-Data#limitations-and-considerations):

> - The maximum number of rows that can be exported using API to .csv is 30,000.
> - Export using Underlying data will not work if the data source is an Analysis Services live connection and the version is older than 2016 and the tables in the model do not have a unique key.
> - Export using Underlying data will not work if the Show items with no data option is enabled for the visualization being exported.
> - If you have applied filters to the visualization, the exported data will export as filtered.
> - When using DirectQuery, the maximum amount of data that can be exported is 16 MB. This may result in exporting less than the maximum number of rows, especially if there are many columns, data that is difficult to compress, and other factors that increase file size and decrease number of rows exported.
> - Power BI only supports export in visuals that use basic aggregates. Export is not available for visuals using model or report measures.
> - Custom visuals, and R visuals, are not currently supported.
> - Power BI admins have the ability to disable the export of data.
> - Concurrent export data requests from the same session are not supported. Multiple requests should be run synchronously.